# Java-implemented migration being filtered out

Tags: java, flyway

Why is my java-implemented migration being filtered out? With debug enabled, I see the following:

**Scanning for classes at classpath:db/migrations**

**Filtering out resource: db/migrations/V18__Move_TE_Highlight_Flds.class (filename: V18__Move_TE_Highlight_Flds.class)**

The class is declared as:

**public class V18__Move_TE_Highlight_Flds extends BaseJavaMigration {**

So I don't understand why the class is being filtered out.

Comment: To clarify, I'm using a mix of both .sql and one .class migrations. Flyway 8.5.12 finds all the .sql files AND the one .class file BUT it then filters out the .class file and reports it as missing.